# How to achieve forced indentation in LightTable after pressing enter after a "{"

Tags: autocomplete, indentation, lighttable

On almost every IDE or text editor intended for code a situation like this is achieved:

```
void foo() {
```

goes to

```
void foo() {
     [cursor here]
}
```

after pressing enter. But in LightTable the line in between the brackets with an indent does not exist, instead the cursor ends before the second bracket. What do you need to add to probably the `user.behaviors` file to make this happen?